# Why Tidal Tails in Disk Galaxies, but not in Ellipticals?

Tags: galaxy, tidal-forces

Why do tidal tails result from only disk galaxies but not ellipticals.

I understand that tidal tails are results of gravitational interactions not strong enough to completely plunge out the material violently. How is that they form only in organized motions (disk) rather than random motion (ellipticals).

Any references to a detailed explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: In your distinction between elliptical or spiral are you referring to the central object or the object being distorted? If it is the former I don't think it holds. If its the later its because spirals are gravitationally 'cold' i.e. more responsive to tides because they are made of centrifugally supported orbits rather than pressure supported ones.

Comment: A comment to my comment: if the central is a spiral and the passage drives the satellite near the disc then it could impact the tails as the host's potential will be flattened there.